# A remark about the Rellich-Kondrachov Compactness Theorem in Evans's PDE book

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

The following is the Rellich-Kondrachov Compactness Theorem in Evans's Partial Differential Equations

> [image]

The author gives a remark as follows

> [image]

I don't understand the first sentence in the Remark. Here are my **questions**:

- > How does one get $W^{1,p}(U)\Subset L^p(U)$ for $p=n$?
- > Why does "$p^*\to\infty$ as $p\to n$" imply the desired embedding?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remember $U$ is bounded, so $W^{1,n}(U) \subset W^{1,p}(U)$ for all $1 \leq p < n$ by Holder. Since $p^*\to \infty$ as $p\to n$, we can choose a fixed $p<n$ close enough to $n$ so that $p^*>n$. Then by the Rellich-Kondrachov compactness thoerem

$$W^{1,n}(U) \subset W^{1,p}(U) \subset\subset L^n(U).$$

Arguing along the same lines, we actually have $W^{1,n}(U) \subset\subset L^q(U)$ for all $1 \leq q < \infty$.