# Poincaré's inequality in a theorem regarding estimates for $W_0^{1,p}$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

It is stated in Evans's *Partial Differential Equations* (2nd edition) that

> [image]
>   [image]

I don't understand the "In particular" part. The case $1\leq p<n$ is obvious since in this case $p\in [1,p^*]$. How is the case $n\leq p\leq\infty$ implied by the former statement?

Comment: The argument needed here is almost the same as in http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1936048/9464

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $p\geq n$ is finite, then use the fact that $W^{1,p}_0(U) \subset W^{1,p'}_0(U)$ for all $p' \leq p$ (as $U$ is bounded). So fix a value of $p'<n$ so that $(p')^* \geq p$. This is possible since $(p')^* \to \infty$ as $p'\to n$. Then use $q=p \leq (p')^*$ in the theorem to get

$$\|u\|_{L^p}\leq C\|Du\|_{L^{p'}} \leq C\|Du\|_{L^p}.$$

The constant $C$ depends on $p'$ and $p$, but really just on $p$ since we can choose $p'$ as a function of $p$.

This gets you the $n \leq p < \infty$ cases. The $p=\infty$ case is easy to prove by hand.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Once one has the $1\leq p<\infty$ case, one can take the limit $p\to\infty$ to get the $p=\infty$ case since $U$ is of finite measure. I'm curious about how you prove it directly.

Comment: You have to be careful taking the limit as $p\to \infty$. There are examples of functions that belong to every $L^p$ space for finite $p$ but not $p=\infty$. You would need to get uniform bounds on the $L^p$ norms independent of $p$.

Comment: Roughly speaking, the direct way is to use the fundamental theorem to write $u(x) = \int_0^1 tDu(tx)\cdot x \, dt$, supposing $u(0)=0$. Then you get $|u(x)| \leq |x|\|Du\|_{L^\infty}$. To make it rigorous you would use an approximation argument via mollification.